# how do I configure my git remote branch in eclipse for a repo on github?

Tags: git, github

I have a project locally that I pushed to github. Each time I am trying to push a commit to github it asks me for the remote url. Can't I configure it so that it will automatically push to my desired branch.

I tried setting up remote tracking in repository view but it starts cloning the repo which I don't need since I already have my branch synced locally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way is to try the following process in a new directory, to see if the issue persists:

- clone your GitHub repo (that way, we are sure the `git remote -v` will show a proper remote for your new local repo)
- git checkout the right branch: switch to the branch you want to work on
- make new commits on it
- `git push -u origin yourBranch`: that will add the upstream (tracking) reference to `origin/yourBranch`.

The next push on that branch can use a simple `git push`.
You won't have to specify again the remote url.